# How to generate initial values for that satisfies some constraints

Tags: python, optimization, initialization

Hi I am trying to solve an optimization problem and I'm stuck because I can't seem to find a way to generate an initial value for my optimization problem.
The constraints that I have to account for are the following :

```
sum(w) = 1     (w is a vector)
w[i] >= 0 for every i
min[i] <= (w.T * beta)[i] <= max[i] where here B is a fixed matrix I have
min2[i] <= sum(w[idx])/len(w) <= max2[i]
```

Here `w` are wights for a portfolio and `idx` are a list of index that relates a single asset to a given macro-asset class, the last constraint is hence imposing some fixed composition of my portoflio wrt some macro asset percentages.

Comment: You may need to provide some test data that we can run that illustrates how it fails.

Comment: it's not that it fails, it's that i have to run an optimization procedure using the scipy optimization library, but here every function asks me to provide an initial value that satisfies the set of equality and inequality restrictions that i wanna impose, but i can't seem to find a way to do so, so i dont even run the optimization because it woouldn't make sense